# "now exiting Console" message in beamer using pythontex

Tags: beamer, python, pythontex

After I asked on other forum, I was told that this behavior is due to python 3.6 code module.

[code module update in python 3.6](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/100)

[image]

I do produce slides for my training presentation with Beamer.
To execute Python code and show result I use the `pythontex` package.

When I use `\pyconsole` environment, I always have this message after the result of the last `\pyconsole` command:

```
 now exiting Console ...
```

I have produced a minimal example of output below.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior?

filename: `pythontex_error.tex`

```
\RequirePackage{currfile}
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme {beaver}}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{ My error : reproductibility }
  \begin{block}{Proportion of couples (a,b) $ \in \left \{ a, ..,z,A,..Z \right \}$}
    \input{./pyconsole_code}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Last pythontex pyconsole environment}
    \input{./pyconsole_last_code}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Have been added on the last pyconsole  output }
    \pyv{  }\\
    \pyv{  }\\
    \pyv{now exiting Console...}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

filename: `pyconsole_code.tex`

```
\tiny
\begin{pyconsole}
a = [(x, y) for x in range(52) for y in range(52) ]
b = [(x, y) for x in range(52) for y in range(52) if x != y]
c = [(x, y) for x in range(52) for y in range(52) if x<y]
\end{pyconsole}

\footnotesize
\begin{pyconsole}
len(b)/len(a)*100, len(c)/len(a)*100
\end{pyconsole}
```

filename: `pyconsole_last_code.tex`

```
\begin{pyconsole}
print("This is the last pyconsole environment")
\end{pyconsole}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please show some code that produces the issue?

Comment: Thanks for editing your post and adding the image - but can you please add the code that produces the image? That would be much more helpful! [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: The problem seems to be with `currfile`: if I remove its call, the output has no strange string.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed in `pythontex`, see https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/100 for more information.